# Rails & JS : Infinite Scrolling

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, pagination, infinite-scroll

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/infinite-scrolling-rails-basics/) to transform my index page in an infinite scrolling.

But the result is that I have some pagination buttons instead of an infinte scrolling
[image]

So this is my code :

```
index.html.erb
```

-

```
<div id="my-annonces">
     <%= render @annonces %>
</div>
<div id="infinite-scrolling">
     <%= will_paginate %>
</div>
```

-

```
AnnoncesController
```

-

```
class AnnoncesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  page_paginate = 6
  @annonces = Annonce.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: page_paginate).order('created_at DESC')
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
end
```

-

```
index.js.erb
```

-

```
   $('#my-annonces').append('<%= j render @annonces %>');
    <% if @annonces.next_page %>
       $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @annonces %>');
    <% else %>
       $(window).off('scroll');
       $('.pagination').remove();
    <% end %>
```

-

This js is never called, Don't now why. If I put it the the view it's called. But I don't know what the `.pagination` is ...

-

As he said, I've created a new file `pagination.js.coffee` inside the javascripts directory.

-

```
jQuery ->
 if $('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0
  console.log "AAAAA "
  $(window).on 'scroll', ->
      console.log "BBBBBB "
    more_posts_url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
      console.log "CCCCC "
    if more_posts_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60
          console.log "DDDDD "
        $('.pagination').html('<img src="/assets/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />')
        $.getScript more_posts_url
    return
  return
```

-

But this file is never called too.

I don't have any errors in rails console, or the js console. I'm note very experienced in JS, so I'm a little bit lots.

Any one know what the problem is ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad,

I've just forgot to include my pagination.js.coffee...
I'm so stupid, sorry guys !

Nevermind, I hope thats my post will help other to use infinte scrolling !

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "forgot to include my pagination.js.coffee"? I went through the tutorial and am having the same issue.